# Is the SO "not a page" code chimeric?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, fun, 404-not-found

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the joke in the Stack Overflow 404 page code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28625/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code)

This code looks chimeric (and the SO syntax highlighter seems to think so!). What languages does it involve? I can see some BrainFuck in there, what else is there?

```
# define v putchar
#   define print(x) main(){v(4+v(v(52)-4));return 0;}
#>+++++++4+[>++++++<-]>+++.----.++++.*/
print(202*2);exit();
#define/*>.@*/exit()
```

Comment: It's a polyglot: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28625/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code

Comment: @quantumSoup: what's the difference between a polyglot and chimera code?

Comment: @BoltClock this code is displayed prominently: http://stackoverflow.com/notapage

Comment: @fredley: I realized. No wonder it was so familiar.

Comment: @Bolt No difference, I am just saying that it *is* a polyglot